# UI Router - Going to non angular app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a few routes in my Angular, and a few apps that exist outside the Angular world.

I'm using html5mode with locationProvider.

eg.

```
app.config(function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

And UI Router. eg.

```
app.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('account.exchange', {
    url: '/exchange',
    templateUrl: 'exchange/exchange.html',
    controller: 'ExchangeCtrl'
  });
});
```

Things are mostly fine. When I click through within the angular app, state changes occur without a full page refresh, I click back and the state goes to my previous state. When I click on a link outside the angular world, it gets served and I can click around there. I can click to get back into the angular app as well.

However - If I begin in my angular app - /app/state1, then go to /app/state2, then go outside angular - eg. to /thisIsAStaticPage.html, then click the back button - the url bar changes but my page doesn't change. No full page refresh (which is what I would expect).

What am I doing wrong with this?

Comment: A bit a clarification needed.  When you hit back from the static page does your angular app load whatever state it was last in? /app/state2 in your example above?  That is the expected behavior without additional logic on your part to prevent it.

Comment: No, it doesn't load the last state. Assume the following - Start in state 1, click to state 2, click back to state 1 - I am now in state 1, url /app/state1. Everything is fine. Then I click to an outside link (physically different box, but on the same base url). /outside link. Loads correctly, looks fine. I then click back. At this point, my browser url displays /app/state1 (expected), but /app/state1 doesn't load (nor does the angular app load at all).